# Prove the associative law for the addition of real numbers using the definition of infimum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The problem asks to prove a few properties of real numbers such as: commutative, associative law among others, however is required to do this under the definition that is given in an Introduction to set theory (Jech, Hrbacek). Where Q is the rational numbers:

$x+y=\inf \{r+s |r,s ∈ \mathbb{Q}, r≥x,\, s≥y \}$

$xy=\inf \{rs |r,s ∈ \mathbb{Q}, r≥x,\, s≥y \}$

I'm not sure how to do this with that definition.

(1) $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$

(2) $x(y+z)=xy+xz$

Thanks for yor help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the definitions of the left and right hand sides and try to see if you can show that they are equal. For example, for associativity:

$$\begin{array}{rcl} (x+y)+z &=& \inf\{t+u | t,u \in \mathbb{Q}, t \ge (x+y), u \ge z \} \\ & =&\inf\{ t+u| t,u \in \mathbb{Q}, u \ge z, t \ge \inf\{ r+s | r,s \in \mathbb{Q}, r \ge x, s \ge y\} \} \\ &=& \inf\{(r+s)+u | r,s,u \in \mathbb{Q}, u \ge z, r \ge x, s \ge y \} \\ &=& \inf\{ r+(s+u)| r,s,u \in \mathbb{Q}, r \ge x, s\ge y, u\ge z \} \\ &=&\inf \{r+v| r,v \in \mathbb{Q}, r \ge x, v \ge \inf\{s+u| s,u \in \mathbb{Q}, s \ge y, u \ge z \} \}  \\ &=&\inf \{r + v | r, v \in \mathbb{Q}, r \ge x, v \ge (y+z) \} \\ &=& x+(y+z) \end{array}$$